# Value of $\lambda$ for two tangents intersect at origin

Tags: circles

[image]

I am not getting any idea . Can anybody provide me a hint

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT:

$$x^2+y^2+8x+8y+16+\lambda(x+y+12)=0$$ represents the equation of the circle passing through the intersections$A,B$ of $$x+y+12=0$$ and 
$$x^2+y^2+8x+8y+16=0$$

Comment: Now finding the points is getting very complicated

Comment: For the circle $$(x+4)^2+(y+4)^2=4^2,$$ any point can be written as $$(-4+4\cos t,-4+4\sin t)$$ can you find the two values of $t?$

Comment: I got t=$\pi $ and $3\pi/2$ . Now how to find the equation of circle

Comment: @user123733, Now when $y=mx$ be a tangent of  $$x^2+y^2+8x+8y+16+\lambda(x+y+12)=0?$$